# Python while loop gives output and continuously puts none as the output instead of rechecking to see if image is there

Tags: python

The output is if the image is not on screen print none and then it keeps repeating that same output even if I put the image on screen, instead of rechecking if the image is on screen.

What I want the program to do is print the correct corresponding output and then check again for the image and continuously do that.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Linux mint cinnamon.

```
import pyautogui
import time

r = None
i = 0
bonus_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('firefox_button.png')
times_clicked = 0


def clickBonusButton():
    global bonus_button
    global r
    while r is None:
        r = bonus_button
        if r != None:
            pyautogui.click(bonus_button)
            print('clicked button')
            print(r)
            continue
        else:
            print(r)
            continue


while i == 0:
    clickBonusButton()
    print('checking...')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: You set `bonus_button` *once*, on the sixth line.  Nothing ever changes its value after that point.  You need to do your `.locateCenterOnScreen()` inside the loop if you want its current result.

Comment: You should test if a variable is None using `is`, instead of `==`. In fact, I think it would make more sense to get rid of that check entirely, since it's just repeating the loop condition. You don't need the `continue` statements inside `clickBonusButton()`.

Comment: I have removed the while loop inside of my function, it's now just an if r is not None. Inside the if and else I am updating the bonus_button variable. I also added a grayscale=False to my bonus_button because the program wasn't always picking up the button. This now works perfectly, thank you.